# Facebook Developer Alert:Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time

Tags: facebook, permissions

I received a message from Facebook.
"Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook. Please update your app accordingly. Read our 모범 사례 for more details."

I can not understand. Clearly read / write permission to make a separate call.
Facebook is a warning, but now and then he deleted the app from.

Please let us know in the wrong part of the development source.
Facebook read / write permissions and prefill image caption, but the answers come back., but only the mail gets sent.
I give tell which part is wrong?

---

Answer (score -1):

Simple: You should not ask for read and write permissions at the same time. (What’s so hard to understand about that?)

When the user connects to your app, i.e. logs in for the first time, you should only ask for read permissions for the data you need for registration in your app, f.e. email and birthday.

Only later, when they f.e. actually want to share something via your app, should you ask for write permission – at that specific point, and not before.