# Getting facebook read and write permissions in a single dialogue window

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to request both [read and write facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) from the user through a single dialogue window? I read that [facebook consider it bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509585/facebook-developer-alertyour-app-asks-for-read-and-write-permissions-at-the-sam) to request both read and write permissions from the user at the same time, but in our situation I find it optimal. I have been through their [requesting and revoking page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking).

We are currently developing an endless runner game for mobile using Unity 3D in which we integrate facebook using the [Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/) provided by facebook themselves.

At the end of the run, the user is asked to connect to facebook to compete against friends. In this case read permission is needed to [get scores / friend profile pictures while write permission is necessary to upload the user's score](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements). Having to prompt the user twice in this situation seems like a bad user experience.

Comment: "while read permission is necessary to upload the user's score"?  Did you mean "write permission"?

Comment: In my opinion you could even make a multiple checklist alert dialog to handle ten permissions at once. Why not?

Comment: @Droppy my bad, that was clearly a typo

Comment: @greenapps can you elaborate on that? I am not sure what "checklist alert dialog" is.

Comment: Have a look at AlertDialog.Builder.setItems(multichecklist). (Sorry for not knowing the exact name now). The IDE will tell you ;-).

Comment: You did not formulate it as such but you want to get read permission from Android and write permission from Facebook?

Comment: @greenapps I'll properly have to format my question then. I want to get both the users read and write permissions from facebook.

Comment: You could add fb to the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we implemented the Facebook API it simple would not work if we did not follow the facebook guidelines of first getting read permissions and the write permissions and I am also pretty sure that their documentation states it, even though I can't find the exact passage at the moment.

I would consider using the Prime31 facebook plugin, thats what we used and it has (atleast had) method calls for handling this double prompt as smoothly as possible. (its called Social Network plugin here: https://prime31.com/plugins)

You could consider giving the user a nice currency reward for doing it so it does not seem as that much of a hassle for the user.

Comment: It does not appear to be possible to get both read and write permission from facebook at the same time. We ended up doing the score handling ourselves.